# Spring Integration file only once from SFTP across several sessions

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration WorkFlow which downloads files from a SFTP directory. This is done with a RemoteFileInboundChannelAdapterSpec and IntegrationFlows.
Spring Integration remembers within a session which files it has already downloaded, can I do this across sessions e.g. through a database and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is done not within the session, but by some specific `FileListFilter` implementation . For your goal we suggest an `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` where its `MetadataStore` could really be based on some shared database. See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound